# MySQL- GROUP and COUNT by date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to figure out the proper syntax for getting query result I need. Here is the scenario:

I am designing a SaaS application and have a table called trips, like so:

```
table.trips  
- trip_id (pk, ai)  
- client_id (fk)  
- shop_id (fk)
- trip_date (date)
```

I need to be able to get the number of trips in the table for each day (by shop_id) and then deliver the number of TRIPS per trip_date, like:

```
DATE         | TRIP SUM  
--------------------------
01-01-2011   | 3
01-02-2011   | 2  
01-03-2011   | 5
```

Any thoughts on the proper syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "by shop id"? There is no `shop_id` in your resultset.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), trip_date , shop_id 
FROM trips 
GROUP BY trip_date , shop_id
```

Comment: You either need to remove the WHERE or put in a WHERE condition. The way it is is invalid SQL.

Comment: Perfect:-) Thanks for your help. Added WHERE shop_id=# and it worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS customvar` always helps with the returned results

Answer (score 11):

If the date column also stores hour and minute you will need to apply a substring function to the date, to only have the **yyyy-mm-dd** part of the date column, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), substring(trip_date,1,10)
FROM trips
GROUP BY substring(trip_date,1,10);
```

Comment: This just saved me ages trying to compile a count of rows by date but not time

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
select 
   DATE(trip_date) as [DATE],
   count(1) as [TRIP SUM]
from
   trips
group by
   DATE(trip_date), shop_id
```

I'm not a mySQL guy, but you will need to use a T-SQL DatePart equivalent, where I have used the `DATE()` function in order to strip the time portion of the date.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT shop_id, trip_date, count(trip_id)
FROM trips
GROUP BY shop_id, trip_date
```

Comment: Please take a moment to expand on this code-only answer regarding how it works and why it is a good idea.  When new users see code-only answers posted by high-repped users they think that this is "how it is done on SO".  Please role model better posting behavior for their sake -- not to mention for the benefit of future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

```
select trip_date,count(*)
from trips
where shop_id=[the shop id]
group by trip_date
```

This will work as long as the date is on the format you showed. If it has also time then you have to remove the time.

Also I do not know if the client_id has to come in in this query, if you have to group by it also then you have to put it along side trip_date on select or group. If you want to filter by it put it in the where.